# How to change Parent font of Kendo MVC treeview

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-treeview, kendo-ui-mvc

I am using Kendo MVC Treeview from Telerik. How can I change font for all parents that has child nodes.

Also is it possible to see lines for treeview?

I tried search on Telerik website , but cannot find anything that's helpful.

Here is how some of my parent node looks like

```
<div class="k-mid"><span class="k-icon k-minus" role="presentation"></span><a class="k-in k-state-focused" href="Test/Edit/1">Node 3</a></div>

<div class="k-top"><span class="k-icon k-minus" role="presentation"></span><a class="k-in k-state-focused" href="Test/Edit/2">Node 7</a></div>
```

Thanks

Comment: You can add lines with style changes http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/treeview/how-to/show-node-lines

Comment: @SteveGreene. Thanks for link. It did helped with lines for treeview. I just need how to change parents font.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This css works for me. Basically, find the k-icons which are the arrows, then set the font on the sibling span.

```
.k-treeview span.k-icon ~ span.k-in {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

EDIT: If the node is an anchor, try:

```
.k-treeview span.k-icon ~ a.k-in {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sample code. But its not working for me. Here is how my nodes look like   `<div class="k-mid"><span class="k-icon k-minus" role="presentation"></span><a class="k-in k-state-focused" href="Test/Edit/1">Node 3</a></div>`
    
    `<div class="k-top"><span class="k-icon k-minus" role="presentation"></span><a class="k-in k-state-focused" href="Test/Edit/2">Node 7</a></div>`